# How can I prevent hard coding the CSS animation below?

Tags: html, css, xml, animation, svg

I'm using `@keyframes` to animate this svg :

```css
.candles {
      width: -webkit-fill-available;
      transition: all 0.5s;
} 
.candles line, path{
    stroke: #5ABCF3;
    animation-name: candle;
    animation-duration: 4s;   
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-direction: alternate;

}
@keyframes candle {

    from { stroke: #5ABCF3 } 
    to { stroke: blue; transform: translateY(-128px);}

}
```

```html
<svg class="candles" width="1782" height="472" viewBox="0 0 1782 472" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="frame">
    <line id="line-1" x1="6.5" y1="219.652" x2="6.5" y2="270.117" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <line id="line-2" x1="35.2988" y1="259.74" x2="35.2988" y2="274.583" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <line id="line-3" x1="62.5488" y1="258.266" x2="62.5488" y2="290.919" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <path id="line-4" d="M96.2578 273.045V323.509" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <path id="line-5" d="M123.475 305.76V322.086" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <path id="line-6" d="M153.799 255.301V328.029" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

in this have few elements and it's okay to hard code it, but when candles ( elements ) are more ... hard coding is not efficient
**I want to be able to declare specific `translateY()` for each `<line>` or `<path>` element.
How can i do that?**

Comment: @RobertLongson my bad, CSS added

Comment: You can use `calc()` and CSS variables inside `translateY()` see if it fits your needs. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-css-variables-for-animation--cms-28868

Answer (score 0):

In this example I use a combination of the pseudo selectors [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Other selectors [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#tree-structural_pseudo-classes) could also be used. I'm not saying that my example is perfect, but if you combine more of them with different CSS property values I think you can get something that looks more of less random.

Aside: You can see that I also experimented with [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). At the  moment this function can only be used in combination with the content property, but as you can read from the link more options will be available in the future. Like setting a type s for seconds.

```css
.candles line,
.candles path {
  stroke: #5ABCF3;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  animation-name: candle;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-delay: attr(data-delay s);
}

.candles *:first-child {
  animation-delay: 1ms;
}

.candles *:first-child {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
}

.candles *:nth-child(odd):nth-child(n+3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 5.5s;
}

.candles *:nth-child(odd):nth-child(n+5) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.candles *:nth-child(even):nth-child(n+5) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes candle {
  from {
    stroke: #5ABCF3
  }
  to {
    stroke: blue;
    transform: translateY(-128px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="candles" width="1782" height="472" viewBox="0 0 1782 472" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="frame">
    <line data-delay="10" x1="6.5" y1="219.652" x2="6.5" y2="270.117" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <line data-delay="0" x1="35.2988" y1="259.74" x2="35.2988" y2="274.583" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <line data-delay="2" x1="62.5488" y1="258.266" x2="62.5488" y2="290.919" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <path data-delay="5" d="M96.2578 273.045V323.509" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <path data-delay="3" d="M123.475 305.76V322.086" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
    <path data-delay="1" d="M153.799 255.301V328.029" stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, but seems like we can't use data attributes in these tags

Comment: @Skinny the data attributes in the example are not really working. The important part is the different CSS pseudo selectors.

Comment: thanks, but i just wanted to be able to move them one by one and i don't know how